# Diaspora admin setup fails

Tags: bundler, diaspora

After creating a pod, I tried to setup an admin user by running:

```
DB=postgres bundle exec rails console production
```

but this failed with:

```
/home/diaspora/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)
from /home/diaspora/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/diaspora/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@diaspora/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
from /home/diaspora/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@diaspora/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/diaspora/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@diaspora/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in `require'
from /home/diaspora/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@diaspora/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone know how to get past this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install a Ruby with Readline support. Look for a package `libreadline-dev`, `libreadline-devel` or similar. After that is installed run `rvm reinstall 2.0`.